# XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal. NOT fetching data from another domain

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to use a PHP file to pull data from a database and convert it to JSON using a $.getJSON call, but I just get the following error:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{af08ce9b-940c-41a3-bd20-e4e5ad1a6d23} Line Number 17, Column 3:
?>
--^
```

Everything I can find says this is because I'm trying to pull the data from another domain, but this isn't the case for me; the website is a Maven web project that's running on a local Glassfish web server.

Here's my PHP file:

```
<?php

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oaaa";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$rows = array();

if (isset($_GET['activity'])) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE type = ? ORDER BY date");
    $stmt->execute(array($_GET['activity']));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Here's my JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('php/query-database.php', {activity: 'Abseiling'}, function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(index, array) {
            $('.events').append(array['title']);
        });

    });
});
```

**UPDATE:** The problem has been resolved, turns out it was simply the fact that my Maven web project couldn't run the PHP files, so the PHP files did not return any data. After creating a PHP project, everything is working fine.

Comment: When you access /php/query-database.php?activity=Abseiling do you get the JSON output?

Comment: No, this is what I'm getting: 

prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE type = ? ORDER BY date"); $stmt->execute(array($_GET['activity'])); $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); } echo json_encode($rows); ?>

Comment: The output of the PHP script is PHP code? If that is the case your server is not processing PHP files. Your browser is thus showing the entire contents of the file as text. Reason you see the above is <?php to -> is being rendered as an HTML tag so not showing up in view, but in view-source you will see your entire file contents.

Comment: Make sure your opening PHP tag is <?php and on its own line, that the file is saved with a .php extension on server, and if you have SuEXEC enabled on server that the file has proper permissions to run.

Comment: The website is currently a Maven web project made in Netbeans, and there was no way to create a new PHP file for this particular project in Netbeans so I just manually created the file in the project directory. I'm assuming Maven web projects must not be able to use/run PHP files (hence Netbeans not allowing me to create one), and thus I'm getting this error. I'll try creating a proper PHP project and see if that works. :)

Comment: Yep, everything working fine now that it's a PHP project instead of a Maven web project. Thanks!